# Compare values in one column to another in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am a little lost here, I feel like this should be really simple. The goal is to take data given with a range in the "# - #" format and see if the "Values" fall within that range. I need to then have a new column indicating if the "Value" was in the range given. The code below was how I thought it should look, but it does not return correct T/F statements.

```
Group<-c("A","B","C")
Value<-c(12,2,200)
Range<-c("5-20","5-20","5-20")

Test<-as.data.frame(cbind(Group,Value,Range))

Test<-separate(Test,Range,into = c("min","max"),sep = "-",remove = T)

Test<-mutate(Test,Pass=Test$min<Test$Value|Test$Value<Test$max))
```

The problem seems to stem from the minimum value this code works as expected

```
Test<-mutate(Test,Pass=Test$Value<Test$max)
```

However, this code returns all FALSE values:

```
Test<-mutate(Test,Pass=Test$min<Test$Value)
```

I must be missing something. Any help on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the ability to rewrite `Range` as two separate vectors (a minimum and a maximum vector) or are you stuck with these constraints?

Comment: If you have been told or advised to use `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`, then you should seriously question the knowledge and experience of the person or blogger that you were using. It is almost never that right way to proceed. If it is one of your teachers I suppose it might be dangerous to directly confront them. It is a frequent cause of newbie errors.

Comment: @DylanRussell unfortunately I am stuck with ```Range``` the way it is. The actual dataset has about 200 different ranges across 25 variations for each range depending on the levels of a specific factor. This is ultimately coded into an RShiny version and spits out a heat map based on the T/F values. Everything except this step is functional.

Comment: @IRTFM  I don't usually work with small self made data frames like this so it is likely a relic from when I was learning R a long time ago. But I see the answer below has a better alternative so thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Yes. It's a puzzle to me why people don't just use the data.fame() function.

Comment: @IRTFM I think I got that usage from the datacamp R basics lessons. If I remember right it used the "as.whatever" functions to change the class of objects in the lessons. Take that with a grain of salt as that was 1-2 years ago though

Comment: Well, yes .... `as.*` functions will coerce but it's the `cbind` function that does the damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check the class of the columns that you have. `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` is incorrect way of creating a dataframe. `cbind` converts all the values to characters. Use `data.frame(...)` instead so that the classes are maintained.
- `separate` returns character columns, use `convert = TRUE` to make them as numeric.
- The condition to check if the `Value` is in range should have `&` and not `|`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Test %>%
  separate(Range,into = c("min","max"),sep = "-", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Pass = Value > min & Value < max)

#  Group Value min max  Pass
#1     A    12   5  20  TRUE
#2     B     2   5  20 FALSE
#3     C   200   5  20 FALSE
```

**data**

```
Group<-c("A","B","C")
Value<-c(12,2,200)
Range<-c("5-20","5-20","5-20")
Test<- data.frame(Group,Value,Range)
```

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks for spending the time on this.